# Adding bottom padding to `last-child` of the list doesn't work

Tags: html, css, html-lists

There is a list, where each list item (`<li class="meaning-word">`) may or may not be followed by a sentence in English (`<li class="sentence-en">` - light-blue font) and sentence in German (`<li class="sentence-de">` - black font).
So the **last** item of the list may be *either one* of those 3. When this list is long, page scrolling will apply and I want the last list item - whatever it will be - to have a `padding-bottom` property.
Imo, it was logical to create a `.meaning > li:last-child` and apply such property to **it** - since all 3 classes (Meaning/English/German) are within the `<ol class="meaning">` class. But this doesn't work.
 [Here](https://jsbin.com/nicegirusu/edit?html,css,output) is the JS Bin with this code, just in case.

```css
      .meaning {
        list-style-type: none;
        counter-reset: item;
        hyphens: auto;
        font-size: calc(0.7em + 1.5vw);
      }

      .meaning > li {
        position: relative;
      }

      .meaning > li::before {
        content: counter(item);
        counter-increment: item;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: calc(-0.7em - 2.5vw);          
      }

      .meaning-word {
        margin-top: 50px;
      }

      .sentences {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        font-size: calc(0.7em + 1.5vw);
        margin-top: 30px;                   
      }

      .sentences > li.sentence-en {
        color: #5d78e5;
      }

      .sentences > li.sentence-de {
        margin-top: 5px;
      }

      .meaning > li:last-child {
        padding-bottom: 10em;      
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
  <ol class="meaning">
    <li class="meaning-word">Meaning1</li>
      <ul class="sentences">
        <li class="sentence-en">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li class="sentence-de">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</li>
      </ul>
    <li class="meaning-word">Meaning2</li>
      <ul class="sentences">
        <li class="sentence-en">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li class="sentence-de">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</li>
    </ul>
  </ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` cannot be a child of an `<ol>` or `<ul>`

Comment: `>` selects only direct children of an element. and the `li` you are trying to access is not a direct element. So, you can use `.meaning li:last-child{}` but I would recommend you to read about CSS selectors first, then use them as needed.

Comment: It’s often a good idea to put your code through a validator e.g. https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: The HTML looks fine to me. (Maybe it's been updated since the comments above.) Anyhow, why not just give the `ol` bottom padding?

Comment: @ThugLife Thank you, but that adds padding after the last item of *each* Meaning block, i.e., after Meaning1 **and** after Meaning2, while I need it **only** after Meaning2 (i.e., the _last_ one) or after any sentence in it - `sentence-en` or `sentence-de`). Like I said - the last item of the list can be either Meaning or sentence-en, or sentence-de _under_ that meaning in the list (like in the code I use).

Comment: @ralph.m OMG, padding applied to `.meaning` worked like a charm, thank you!!! I was so stupid to overlook this simple solution.